# How to attach image file using php mail

Tags: php, email

Hoi Everyone, I'm new in php programming. I just wanted to ask a little help from you guys about how can I attach an image file using php mail() function. I've already tried html/text and it works great and it sends to my email. but the problem is when I change the content type to image/jpg. it's not working. All I need now is a way to attach the image file in php mail() not using any php libraries. Thank you .

Comment: To clarify, embedding an image into the email with HTML does not meet your requirements, correct?

Comment: Can you host the images on a web server and reference the images using HTML?

Comment: Im using my localhost for sending my email. Ive done sending email with a html/text and it  works fine but for images it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$to = 'test@gmail.com';
$subject = 'test subject';
$message = 'this is <strong>html</strong> <img src="http://www.test.com/image.test.png" >       message';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Try this. 
provide exact path of image which is located on server.

Comment: Hi Nitin, Actually im using a button where I will search for a certain file then attch it to my email. Is there a possible way to do that.

Comment: You have to save that uploaded image on server. And provide path of image which is on server.

Comment: Does it mean I cannot choose any image file in my laptop and just attach it to my email. All i need to do is to save all the images to the server. by the way I'm using my localhost.